# sbt and play: "test" works "test:run" not

Tags: java, jenkins, sbt, playframework-2.0

I try to establish a build pipeline on Jenkins with a Play(2.0.2) project.

As I want to just build the sources once and use the classes for downstream builds, I now have created a "compile"-job, that runs "sbt test:compile". That works so far.

The next job should then just run the compiled tests. If I use "sbt test" it works as expected, but compiles the sources again.

But if I try to run "sbt test:run" it says:

```
[info] Loading project definition from ~/myproject/project
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file: ~/myproject/)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error] {file:~/myproject/test:run: No main class detected.
```

The same happens locally. I can run "sbt test" but not "sbt test:run". Same error.

Is there someone who can point me to the right direction?

Comment: Are you using the same workspace for both jobs?

Comment: Also, `test:run` runs main classes defined in the test sources similar to how `compile:run` runs main classes in the main sources.  If there isn't a main class, there is nothing to run.

Comment: CIGuy, yes. I'm using the same workspace. Thank you @Mark, I'd like to mark your comment as answer. Could you please post it again as answer? I Have a different question now: How would I use sbt to run the unit-tests (JUnit) on precompiled sources? Should I write a MainClass to do this? It seems I have to add a [junit-interface](https://github.com/szeiger/junit-interface) as dependency which seems strange as they are running fine when I do "sbt clean test"

Comment: Done.  It would probably be best to make the new question a new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test:run` runs main classes defined in the test sources similar to how `compile:run` runs main classes in the main sources.  If there isn't a main class, there is nothing to run.